# Prioritize click polyline instead of marker google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app in which lines are drawn and above these I have a marker that shows the information of the line.

- The lines are clickable
- I'm using Bitmap, Paint and Canvas to draw the marker.

Code for draw the lines

```
Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(line.getPolylineOptions());
polyline.setTag(linea);
polyline.setClickable(clickeable);
polyline.setZIndex(1.0f);
```

Code for draw markers

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(150, 30, conf);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setTextSize(18);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawText(text, 15, 15, paint);

canvas.save();

Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .zIndex(-1.0f)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
);
```

I need that when clicking on the line click on this and not on the marker.

I have tried with Z-Index but it does not work.

Please help.

Comment: instead of setting -1.0f for the marker, have you tried setting the poly line z to say 5.0f?

Comment: Yes, I try with z-index in line, but but work, in google documentation explain a situation... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=es-419#click-index

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to prioritize the line instead of the marker.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=es-419#click-index

> Markers are effectively considered to be in a separate z-index group compared to other overlays or shapes (polylines, polygons, circles, and/or ground overlays), regardless of the z-index of the other overlays. If multiple markers, overlays or shapes are overlaid on top of each other, the click event is cycled through the cluster of markers first, then triggered for other clickable overlays or shapes, based on their z-index values.

Instead I call the same method in:

```
onMarkerClick ()
```

And

```
OnPolylineClickListener ()
```

The same functionality is used when clicking on the line or the marker of this.